# Can an Aegis stack 2 improved damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, aegis

I have a cascade of questions relative to customization points and their use but I think an all-in-one question is better. I can divide that as well as you prefer.

Can a 2 level Aegis with 14 power points and 4 customization points stack improved damage (2cp) and improved damage again (2+2 cp)?

Because he is 2hand weapon fighter (not the class), he can stacks +6 on damage (due to the previous), right? Can he do this with astral skin?

If he does this with astral armor, can he stack Brawn (as free customization) + Improved damage (as free customization) + Improved damage (paying 2 cp)  + Improved damage (paying 2 cp) for a  total = +2+3+3+3= +11 damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unless specified otherwise, a customization may not be selected multiple times.

The improved damage customization does not note otherwise, so no, you cannot select it multiple times, and if you somehow got it multiple times, they would not stack.

You can select improved damage, paying 2 customization points, in order for your astral skin to benefit. Note that because astral armor grants improved damage, if you pay 2 customization points for improved damage yourself, you wind up with two copies of it while in astral armor mode—but they do not stack. This makes the improved damage customization a waste while in astral armor mode.

Brawn can be selected alongside improved damage—as the astral armor does for free. Its effects “stack,” sort of, with improved damage—the +2 enhancement bonus to Strength increases your Strength modifier by +1, which increases your damage by +1 with light or one-handed weapons, or by +1 or +2 for two-handed weapons (depending on how much Strength you had previously). That increase to damage stacks with the +2 from improved damage. Also, since brawn can be selected multiple times starting at 5th level, at that point you can choose brawn, paying 2 customization points, and not have it wasted when in astral armor.